# How to add space between some subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

How can I adjust the whitespace between some subplots?  In the example below, let's say I want to eliminate all whitespace between the 1st and 2nd subplots as well as between the 3rd and 4th and increase the space between the 2nd and 3rd?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Simple data to display in various forms
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

f, ax = plt.subplots(4,figsize=(10,10),sharex=True)

ax[0].plot(x, y)
ax[0].set_title('Panel: A')

ax[1].plot(x, y**2)

ax[2].plot(x, y**3)
ax[2].set_title('Panel: B')
ax[3].plot(x, y**4)

plt.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 8):

To keep the solution close to your code you may use create 5 subplots with the middle one being one forth in height of the others and remove that middle plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Simple data to display in various forms
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

f, ax = plt.subplots(5,figsize=(7,7),sharex=True, 
                     gridspec_kw=dict(height_ratios=[4,4,1,4,4], hspace=0))

ax[0].plot(x, y)
ax[0].set_title('Panel: A')

ax[1].plot(x, y**2)

ax[2].remove()

ax[3].plot(x, y**3)
ax[3].set_title('Panel: B')
ax[4].plot(x, y**4)


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You would need to use [`GridSpec`](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) to have different spaces between plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np

# Simple data to display in various forms
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

f = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
gs0 = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1)

gs00 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 1, subplot_spec=gs0[0], hspace=0)
ax0 = f.add_subplot(gs00[0])
ax0.plot(x, y)
ax0.set_title('Panel: A')
ax1 = f.add_subplot(gs00[1], sharex=ax0)
ax1.plot(x, y**2)

gs01 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 1, subplot_spec=gs0[1], hspace=0)
ax2 = f.add_subplot(gs01[0])
ax2.plot(x, y**3)
ax2.set_title('Panel: B')
ax3 = f.add_subplot(gs01[1], sharex=ax0)
ax3.plot(x, y**4)

plt.show()
```

[image]